# javafx tableview selectall fails when table is empty

Tags: javafx, tableview

selectAll() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the table is empty and in multiple selection mode.

The selectAll() is always called by Ctrl+A key typed event.

The questions are:

1) Should selectAll() handle the case of the empty table and no exception thrown?

2) Is there a way to disable key typed event 'Ctrl+A' when the table is empty or could I just override the selectAll method?

Thanks all.

Comment: Which version of JavaFX are you using?

Comment: I'm using JDK8 production release.